# How to iterate through the data of a column in a sql case statement in dbt?

Tags: sql, dbt

Newbie in dbt here.

I need to do a case statement, something like this:

```
case when PROPERTY_NAME = 'xxx' and EVENT_CATEGORY = 'xxx' and EVENT_ACTION LIKE '%xxx%' and EVENT_LABEL like '%xxx%'
                then 'xxx' 
(...)
```

on property name, I need to iterate through a list of data from a column of a table.

Is it doable though a macro?

Answer (score 2):

To get data into the jinja context, you can use the `run_query` macro to execute arbitrary SQL and return the results as an Agate table. There is an [example in the dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) for how to use that to return the distinct values from a column.

This use case is so common, there is also a macro in dbt-utils for it called [`get_column_values`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_column_values-source). This macro returns the distinct values from a column as an array (list). The example from those docs:

```sql
-- Returns a list of the payment_methods in the stg_payments model_
{% set payment_methods = dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('stg_payments'), column='payment_method') %}

{% for payment_method in payment_methods %}
    ...
{% endfor %}

...
```

(Note that you need to first install the `dbt-utils` package. [Docs for that here](https://hub.getdbt.com/dbt-labs/dbt_utils/latest/)).

If you are trying to check membership in this list of values, you could do something like this:

```sql
{% set properties = dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('your_model'), column='property') %}
{% set properties_str = properties | join("', '") %}
case
    when 
        PROPERTY_NAME in ('{{ properties_str }}')
        and EVENT_CATEGORY = 'xxx' 
        and EVENT_ACTION LIKE '%xxx%' 
        and EVENT_LABEL like '%xxx%'
    then 'xxx'
...
```

Or if you want to iterate over that list:

```sql
{% set properties = dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('your_model'), column='property') %}
case
    {% for property in properties %}
    when 
        PROPERTY_NAME = '{{ property }}'
        and EVENT_CATEGORY = 'xxx' 
        and EVENT_ACTION LIKE '%xxx%' 
        and EVENT_LABEL like '%xxx%'
    then '{{ property }}'
    {% endfor %}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best strategy depends on what you want to do. If all you need is the list of all columns, you could use something like [get_columns_in_relation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/adapter#get_columns_in_relation) and use the results to loop over in your case statement:

```sql
{%- set columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(ref('model')) -%}

case
  when
  {% for column in columns %}
  {{column.name}} = 'xxx' {{ 'and' if not loop.last }}
  {% endfor %}
...
```

If you don't need every column, you could either exclude some columns from the resulting list or (better IMO) just define the columns you need in a jinja variable and loop over those.

If you need the **data** from one of the columns, you can use the (similar) [run_query](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) macro (or the [get_column_values](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/get_column_values.sql) macro in dbt-utils). These have the same pattern of use - ie. retrieve something into the jinja layer of dbt and then use that layer to template out some sql.